# Node, Express, Ajax, and Jade Example

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, pug

I'm looking for a simple example of a Node/Express/Jade page being updated using an Ajax call with both the client and server side code.

I'm having a bit of trouble putting it all together in my head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are great many ways this could be done and it's not immediately apparent which approach you want to take.

I suppose the simplest scenario would be to add some client-side logic to fetch pieces of html from the server and update the client. This is easily achieved using jQuery (put it inside a document ready block to wire up the event):

```
$('#button').click(function() {
     $.get('/some/url', {foo: 42}, function(result) {
         $('#target').html(result);
     }
}
```

This way all your html is generated on the server and you simply fetch and insert it into the page as needed.

You could also fetch json from the server and render the html on the client, but that is one of the alternative approaches. I highly recommend giving [TodoMVC](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) a look - it's a todo-list application with many different implementations (each using a different framework) and therefore a great learning resource for the various approaches and helper libraries.

I'd also recommend the [Hands-on Node.js](http://nodetuts.com/handson-nodejs-book.html) book. It will help you understand routing and how to get started with Node.

Comment: Thanks Morten.  I understand routing in node fine.  I appreciate the example you gave above, but what about the server side?  Do I pass a jade template to the ajax request?  what about partials?

Comment: You do the same for all server-side requests, except that some urls will map to handlers that render a partial view. That could just be a regular Jade template, except that it'll only include the markup you want rendered (and not the full page html).

Comment: @MortenMertner To render that partial view, or to call the server-side function that does, what would an example AJAX route be from the client side?

Comment: @AndrewPeacock I suppose that's up to you, as it depends on what routes you have on the server. For instance, you could have a server route mapped to the url `/products/details` that renders a full page for get requests and a partial view for post requests. On the client you would use `$.post('/products/details', {id:42}, function(result) {...});` to execute the ajax/post request (using jQuery), which would then return the partial view from the server. You could also use separate urls for the partial views if that's your preference.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock I think it just clicked.  I'm feeling a bit stupid right about now.  The node server is responding with the pre-rendered partial view not a whole page with doc type, header, title, etc.?  This seems safer.  Rather than getting an object back that the client side javascript has to render, the server side jade does it for you and returns the html ready to go?  Is all that correct?

Comment: @TimDrake That was actually what I was trying to figure out... I wanted to try and insert/render a jade partial instead of having to render all the content out from an object on the client-side.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the concept I was trying to get across! Glad it starts to make sense. FWIW rendering partials on the client can be a smarter approach, as it reduces the load on the server and saves bandwidth (JSON is smaller than HTML). I use the KnockoutJS library for this purpose, I'd recommend giving it a look once you're more comfortable with everything :)

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help.  I really appreciate it.  I have another question posted [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083358/getting-results-from-node-persist[/link] so if you guys have a minute please help me with that one also. Thanks again.