# Ajax with node.js/jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, pug

I'm searching for a way to use ajax running on node.js, express and jade as template-engine without routing to subpages. I read this: [Node, Express, Ajax, and Jade Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713600/node-express-ajax-and-jade-example)

But this doesn't work for me. I don't want to make a route to a partial part of page, so the user could access the partial page. I just want to serve a convertet jade file in a part of the website.

I think about something like this:

```
$( ".trigger" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( ".result" ).load( "ajax/test.jade" );
});
```

How could I do this without setting a route in node.js so the user could access the subpage without accessing the whole page.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you send the file as a GET parameter:

```
var jade = require('jade'),
    fs = require('fs');

app.get('/ajax', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(req.query.file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;     
        var fn = jade.compile(data);
        var html = fn({});
        res.send(html);
    });
});
```

and send request like

```
/ajax?file=test.jade
```

If you do  the things like that you will have only one route.

Comment: you could also use a route param

Answer (score 0):

(Still requires a route but) You could set up a route that only provides a valid response if it is an ajax request, and a 4xx if otherwise

```
app.get('/path', function(req, res) {
  if(req.xhr)
  {
    ...
  }
});
```

`req.xhr` Express [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.xhr).

Comment: I understand this like: "it checks if it's a jquery ajax request". Right?
Do i have to check the requesting ip to be sure that no other domain than mine loads my content?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. If someone *really* wants to get at your content they can do. If not then you'll need some form of authentication/authorization mechanism.

Comment: I know they ould read out my content but I don't want to make it possible to just put them into a div with a link... 
and i want the users to use my whole page and not parts of them. But your answer gave me some infos I really could use. So thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* place a jade template (or HTML file) in the public folder on your website, assuming you have it set up.

For example, in the app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Place the template/file in (or any subfolder):

```
/public/example.html
```

Then you can use `$.get` to load the file, like the link you provided:

```
$.get('/example.html', function(result) {
    $('#test').html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with ajax call

Server side:

```
router.get('/user/letterlist', function(req, res) {
    // ... some operations
    res.render('userLetterList', { title: 'test', rows : rows? rows: null, pageCount: pageCount,itemCount: itemCount });
});
```

Client side index.jade

```
extends layout
block content
div(id="userLettersList")
    button(type="button" class="btn btn-success")
        {success}
script.
    $(".btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/user/letterlist",
            success: function(data){
                $("#userLettersList").html(data) ;
            }
        });
    });
```

client side userLetterList.jade

```
table(id="UserLetters" class="table table-striped table-bordered")
  thead
   ....
```

The problem is when push on the button to load data into the div, it will retrieve and show, but the page redirect to nowhere with a blank page, after some m-seconds.

Comment: I used document.write() in target jade file, It was the problem.

Comment: How did you solve "$ is undefined" problem. Getting that. Thanks